# Will the browser opens every time with the same profile after setting it in selenium code

Tags: selenium, firefox-profile

I have done some coding to set firefox browser profile to download the file automatically into the download directory.
When the browser launches by selenium webdriver it loads the settings which i have set.

Will the browser launches with same profile after removing that part of profile setting code, for every execution of the program.

Please let me know

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will load default profile if you remove your profile setting code and run it again. By default it would use default profile until it is mentioned in the initialization code.